# Justify label text vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text, label, justify

Does anyone know how to justify the text of a label in vb.net 2010? I know it can be justified center right or left but I want it justified as microsoft word does.

ty

Comment: have you try dock on property ?

Comment: What do you mean "as microsoft word does" - what options are there other than center right or left?

Comment: I mean all lines with the same length

Comment: That's a word processor feature, it is not trivial to implement.  A Label just isn't a word processor.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a simple way to do this in vb.net 2010. It is possible to use the GDI function [DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171753.aspx) to do it, but it's normally done for form labels. Another way is to save the text from a word processor as a bitmap and include it in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to put some paragraph in in your form? I suggest you use a webbrowser control..